# LEFT JOIN performance for WHERE on secondary table

Tags: mysql

I've been developing for years and through out the carrier I've been using only LEFT JOIN as it provides a more logical sense of mapping my one to many data.

However recently I ran across a performance thought:

Say I have table user with millions of rows and table gender with only 2 rows

```
user                                gender
=====================               ================
id name      genderId               id gender show
=====================               ================
1  Sam       1                      1  Male   0
2  Samantha  2                      2  Female 1
3  Another millions of records
```

If I'm doing

```
select * from user u left join gender g on u.genderId = g.id where g.show = 1;
```

Does SQL engine joins the whole million user records first, then scan the million rows of records for join projected value?

Or is the engine smart enough to query and join only the rows with correct gender? Or is RIGHT JOIN the correct method to provide best performance?

If the behavior is dependent on engine type, let's talk about MySQL InnoDB.

Comment: Show the `EXPLAIN query` output. Even if you have a gender.id pinned at 2, `genderId` in user may not be indexed, and even if it was it would be a large proportion of a secondary index, and you still need to look up name and id, so it might not be used. `LEFT` vs `RIGHT` won't matter at all. `LEFT JOIN` should be used when there isn't always RHS match, rather than just one to many, even a basic `INNER JOIN` does many to many.

Comment: Your join is INNER JOIN in practice, because a condition by right table presents in WHERE clause.

Comment: Your where condition on the outer joined table turns the outer join back into an inner join

Comment: DBMS engines are not smart enough to fetch only required entries. Bad news is that nobody is smart enough. Mankind is not able to operate `sets` at all. All we can do is to emulate the `sets` by `lists` and perform the `search` instead of `fetch`. Therefore the correct question should sound like that: "Why this query over that tables with that indexing and that cardinalities is slow?"

Comment: What do you want to happen when `user.gender_id = 3` and there is no corresponding row in the table `gender`.

Answer (score 1):

Remember how SQL works: construct a set of tuples (rows) based on the given tables and joins, then filter those based on any where clause.
Because you have a where condition on the "right" table, your outer join is effectively converted into an inner join.

To retain the "outer-ness" of the join, put the filter condition into the join construct, rather than in the where clause:

```
select * 
from      user u 
left join gender g 
     on  u.genderId = g.id 
     and g.show = 1 
[where ...]
```

Comment: that;s no a requirement of how it works, the planner is free to reorganise the query so long as the same set of results come out (modulo extensions like incomplete group bys)

Comment: @Jasen By index hints we can force the planner to do exactly we want.